# How do I use an array I've created within my Test file

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

So I have created a js array for a list of postcodes. The array is as below in the code: -

`//postcode.js file
var postcode = [
    "b28 8ND", 
    "b49 6BD", 
    "b28 0ST", 
    "b31 4SU",
    "B92 9AH",
];`

What I need to do is in my test randomly select a postcode for this js file to enter into a text field when running my automation tests. How do I go about doing this? An example would be much appreciated as I can't find much on the internet & I'm quite new to TestCafe & javascript. Below is what I have in my test file: -

`//test.js file
.click(page.create.withAttribute('mattooltip', 'Create job'))`

At this point I need to randomly select 1 of the postcodes from the postcode.js file

Comment: "An example would be much appreciated" - YES, please post your code so we have something to work with.  Show your array, how it is generated, things of that nature.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "postcode" is an array, you can generate a random index as shown below:

```
var s = 55;
var random = function() {
   s = Math.sin(s) * 10000;
   return s - Math.floor(s);
};
//...
var postIndex = Math.floor(random() * postcode.length);
var currentPost = postcode[postIndex];
```

For example:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

const postcode = [
    "b28 8ND", 
    "b49 6BD", 
    "b28 0ST", 
    "b31 4SU",
    "B92 9AH",
];

var s = 55
var random = function() {
    s = Math.sin(s) * 10000;
    return s - Math.floor(s);
};

test('My first test', async t => {

    var postIndex = Math.floor(random() * postcode.length);
    var currentPost = postcode[postIndex];

    console.log(currentPost)

    await t        
        .typeText('#developer-name', currentPost);
});
```

Comment: So I have implemented the above as this: `var number = 100
var random = function() {
   number = Math.sin(number) * 10000;
   return number - Math.floor(number);
};
var postcodeIndex = Math.floor(random() * postcode.length);
var currentPostcode = postcode[postcodeIndex];` Then in my test I am trying to do the following: `.typeText(page.input(currentPostcode))` however I'm getting an error stating `The "text" argument is expected to be a non-empty string, but it was undefined.`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong at this point?

Comment: I have added the complete test to the Answer, which works properly on my side. I hope it will be a good starting point for you and you will be able to adapt this solution to your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood you want to pick a random element from your array

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length );
alert(arr[randomIndex])
```

If i am wrong and this is not what you want, please edit your post and explain your question a little bit better

Comment: It's an example so now you can put it working with your postal codes. The logic is the same