# How do I pass variable data between tests

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to do something similar to this [post on TestCafe](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/how-to-pass-data-between-tests/693)

I am generating a random email in my `helper.js` file. I would like to use this random email to log in the `test.js` file.

This is how I am creating my email in the helper.js

```
var randomemail = 'test+' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + '@gmail.com'
```

This is how I want to use it in my `test.js` file

```
.typeText(page.emailInput, randomemail)
```

I have tried several things without luck. How could I go about using the generated email in my `test.js` file?

Comment: Try the solution from the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303283/how-do-i-use-an-array-ive-created-within-my-test-file/51307889#51307889. If this does not help, provide your entire test code.

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

**1) Use the Fixture Context Object (ctx)**

```
fixture(`RANDOM EMAIL TESTS`)
    .before(async ctx => {
        /** Do this to initialize the random email and if you only want one random email 
         *  for the entire fixture */

        ctx.randomEmail = `test+${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}@gmail.com`;
    })
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        // Do this if you want to update the email between each test

        t.fixtureCtx.randomEmail = `test+${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}@gmail.com`;
    })

test('Display First Email', async t => {
    console.log(t.fixtureCtx.randomEmail);
})

test('Display Second Email', async t => {
    console.log(t.fixtureCtx.randomEmail);
})
```

**2) Declare a variable outside of the fixture**

```
let randomEmail = '';

fixture(`RANDOM EMAIL TESTS`)
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        // Do this if you want to update the email between each test

        randomEmail = `test+${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}@gmail.com`;
    })

test('Display First Email', async t => {
    console.log(randomEmail);
})

test('Display Second Email', async t => {
    console.log(randomEmail);
})
```