# How can I use the same value as written in the Json during the same test execution in the testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have been trying to use the value from the JSON that I have got added successfully using fs.write() function,

There are two test cases in the same fixture, one to create an ID and 2nd to use that id. I can wrote the id successfully in the json file using fs.write() function and trying to use that id using importing json file like var myid=require('../../resources/id.json')

The json file storing correct id of the current execution but I get the id of first test execution in 2nd execution.

For example, id:1234 is stored during first test execution and id:4567 is stored in 2nd test execution. During 2nd test execution I need the id:4567 but I get 1234 this is weird, isn't it?

I use it like
t.typeText(ele, myid.orid)

my json file contains only id like {"orid":"4567"}

I am new to Javascript and Testcafe any help would really be appreciated

### Write File class

```
const fs = require('fs')
const baseClass =require('../component/base')
class WriteIntoFile{
    constructor(orderID){
        const OID = {
            orderid: orderID
        }
        const jsonString = JSON.stringify(OID)
        fs.writeFile(`resources\id.json`, jsonString, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error writing file', err)
            } else {
                console.log('Successfully wrote file')
            }
        })
    }
}
export default WriteIntoFile
```

I created 2 different classes in order to separate create & update operations and call the functions of create & update order in single fixture in test file

### Create Order class

```
class CreateOrder{

        ----
        ----
        ----
    async createNewOrder(){
    //get text of created ordder and saved order id in to the json file
        -----
        -----
        -----
   const orId= await baseclass.getOrderId();
   new WriteIntoFile(orId)
   console.log(orId)
   
        -----
        -----
        -----
}
}export default CreateOrder
```

### Update Order class

```
var id=require('../../resources/id.json')
class UpdateOrder{
async searchOrderToUpdate(){
     await t
    ***//Here, I get old order id that was saved during previous execution***
    .typeText(baseClass.searchBox, id.orderid)
    .wait(2500)
    .click(baseClass.searchIcon)
    .doubleClick(baseClass.orderAGgrid)
    console.log(id.ordderid)
    
    ----
    ----
    async updateOrder(){
        this.searchOrderToUpdate()
        .typeText(baseClass.phNo, '1234567890')
        .click(baseClass.saveBtn) 
    }
    
}export default UpdateOrder
```

### Test file

```
const newOrder = new CreateOrder();
const update = new UpdateOrder();
const role = Role(`siteurl`, async t => {
    await t 
   login('id')
    await t
   .wait(1500)
  },{preserveUrl:true})

  test('Should be able to create an Order', async t=>{
    await newOrder.createNewOrder();
  });
  test('Should be able to update an order', async t=>{
       
    await update.updateOrder();
  });
```

Comment: Please share code from your whole test file, e.i. both test cases that work with the json file. Just off the top of my head: is there any reason to store the id in a file, then read the file again, parse the json string in it and only then use it? Wouldn't it be easier to use just a variable?

Comment: I have added my code, please review it and suggest, thanks

Comment: Alright, I added my answer. I answer your question in the second part, but I hope you'll read it all and make changes to your test code.

Answer (score 1):

I'll reply to this, but you probably won't be happy with my answer, because I wouldn't go down this same path as you proposed in your code.

I can see a couple of problems. Some of them might not be problems right now, but in a month, you could struggle with this.

**1/ You are creating separate test cases that are dependent on each other.**

This is a problem because of these reasons:

- what if `Should be able to create an Order` doesn't run? or what if it fails? then `Should be able to update an order` fails as well, and this information is useless, because it wasn't the update operation that failed, but the fact that you didn't meet all preconditions for the test case
- how do you make sure `Should be able to create an Order` always runs before `hould be able to update an order`? There's no way! You can do it like this when one comes before the other and I think it will work, but in some time you decide to move one test somewhere else and you are in trouble and you'll spend hours debugging it. You have prepared a trap for yourself. I wrote [this answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/45446/testcafe-how-to-configure-the-tests-in-the-same-spec-file-to-execute-sequentia) on this very topic, you can read it.
- you can't run the tests in parallel
- when I read your test file, there's no visible hint that the tests are dependent on each other. Therefore as a stranger to your code, I could easily mess things up because I have no way of knowing about it without going deeper in the code. This is a big trap for anyone who might come to your code after you. Don't do this to your colleagues.

**2/ Working with files when all you need to do is pass a value around is too cumbersome.**

I really don't see a reason why you need to same the id into a file. A slightly better approach (still violating 1/) could be:

```js
const newOrder = new CreateOrder();
const update = new UpdateOrder();

// use a variable to pass the orderId around
// it's also visible that the tests are dependent on each other
let orderId = undefined;

const role = Role(`siteurl`, async t => {
    // some steps, I omit this for better readability
}, {preserveUrl: true})

test('Should be able to create an Order', async t=>{
    orderId = await newOrder.createNewOrder();
});

test('Should be able to update an order', async t=>{
   await update.updateOrder(orderId);
});
```

Doing it like this also slightly remedies what I wrote in 1/, that is that it's not visible at first sight that the tests are dependent on each other. Now, this is a bit improved.

Some other approaches how you can pass data around are mentioned [here](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/how-to-pass-data-between-tests/693/3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488794/how-do-i-pass-variable-data-between-tests).

Perhaps even a better approach is to use [`t.fixtureCtx` object](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/fixturectx.html):

```js
const newOrder = new CreateOrder();
const update = new UpdateOrder();

const role = Role(`siteurl`, async t => {
    // some steps, I omit this for better readability
}, {preserveUrl:true})

test('Should be able to create an Order', async t=>{
    t.fixtureCtx.orderId = await newOrder.createNewOrder();
});

test('Should be able to update an order', async t=>{
   await update.updateOrder(t.fixtureCtx.orderId);
});
```

Again, I can at least see the tests are dependent on each other. That's already a big victory.

---

Now back to your question:

> During 2nd test execution I need the id:4567 but I get 1234 this is weird, isn't it?

No, it's not weird. You required the file:

```js
var id = require('../../resources/id.json')
```

and so it's loaded once and if you write into the file later, you won't read the new content unless you read the file again. [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) is a function in Node to load modules, and it makes sense to load them once.

This demonstrates the problem:

```js
const idFile = require('./id.json');
const fs = require('fs');

console.log(idFile); // { id: 5 }
const newId = {
    'id': 7
};
fs.writeFileSync('id.json', JSON.stringify(newId));
// it's been loaded once, you won't get any other value here
console.log(idFile); // { id: 5 }
```

**What you can do to solve the problem?**

You can use [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options):

```js
const idFile = require('./id.json');
const fs = require('fs');

console.log(idFile); // { id: 5 }
const newId = {
    'id': 7
};
fs.writeFileSync('id.json', JSON.stringify(newId));
// you need to read the file again and parse its content
const newContent = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('id.json'));
console.log(newContent); // { id: 7 }
```

And this is what I warned you against in the comment section. That this is too cumbersome, inefficient, because you write to a file and then read from the file just to get one value.

What you created is not very readable either:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const baseClass =require('../component/base')
class WriteIntoFile{
    constructor(orderID){
        const OID = {
            orderid: orderID
        }
        const jsonString = JSON.stringify(OID)
        fs.writeFile(`resources\id.json`, jsonString, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error writing file', err)
            } else {
                console.log('Successfully wrote file')
            }
        })
    }
}
export default WriteIntoFile
```

All these operations for writing into a file are in a constructor, but a constructor is not the best place for all this. Ideally you have only variable assignments in it. I also don't see much reason for why you need to create a new class when you are doing only two operations that can easily fit on one line of code:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('orderId.json', JSON.stringify({ orderid: orderId }));
```

Keep it as simple as possible. it's more readable like so than having to go to a separate file with the class and decypher what it does there.